# How to iterate arrays in an FCM data payload?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to get each item if the `data` payload contains an array? If it was not an array, I could retrieve the value in `override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?)` by `remoteMessage.data.get("item")`, but doing the samething on `items` returned the raw JSON string.

```
{
  "to": "/topics/stack",
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "key1",
        "title": "Hello world"
      },
      {
        "key": "key2",
        "title": "Hello world 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ItemsModel{
   private String key;
   private String title;
   //getters///
   //setters///
}    


String dataMessagePayLoad = remoteMessage.getData();
    if(dataMessagePayLoad!=null){
      private Gson gson = new Gson();
      List<ItemsModel> response = gson.fromJson(dataMessagePayLoad , new TypeToken<List<ItemsModel>>() {
                                }.getType());
    }
```

try using this, i am using the Gson library to convert the json into list

Comment: `String dataMessagePayLoad = remoteMessage.getData();` is giving error of casting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert a string to JSON

```
String itmes=remoteMessage.data.get("data");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(items);
JSONArray itemsArray=jsonObject.optJSONArray("items");
```

you can have array items in `itemsArray`.

Comment: JSONObject(items) threw an exception. The message was array cannot be an object, something like that. I used JSONArray(items) instead.

Comment: Ya, you are correct.It's my bad you have to use 'data' instead of 'items', get data object from then you can get jsonArray.check updated answer.